# Azure Devops - Preventing double test execution in pipeline if Test DLL is referenced by other Test DLL

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

When building an artifact, the build pipeline is filtered on something like `*tests.dll` so all test projects are built.
However, an UI test project also references an API test project because it uses some API calls as well. This results in the API test DLL to be included twice in the artifact.

The consequence is that the release pipeline finds and runs all the API tests two times (because the DLL is present twice). It gets worse if that API test project is used by many more projects...

How to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Extract the API call logic into a third project and reference it from both your tests projects

Comment: We have a third project with API client etc. But API Test project does some specific implementation (e.g. create a customer) that is also needed in UI test setup. I would need to extract specific test logic to a project without tests? Is that the only solution?

Comment: It makes sense to extract this logic anyways for clarity of the code, and it is the cheapest and simplest solution. Also, I feel like you can solution the problem in your pipeline but you did not provide any informations about it.

Comment: What additional info would you like to see? It's just a basic Run Test task that takes the build artifact as input.

Comment: Can you provide Screenshots or Yaml code of the pipeline ? It will show us what Tasks are you using exactly or anything we might need to help you

Comment: Added one of release pipeline. As you can see, filters on DLL and Category obviously don't help because duplicates of DLL matches those criteria as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210359/discussion-between-spidyx-and-fdm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommand you to extract the the API call logic into a third class library and reference it from both the tests projects.
In this way the tests projects will not depend on each others.